# string.substring fails on my strings

Tags: c#, string, substring

I have the below piece of code:

```
string date = dtxt.Substring(5, 2) + @"/" + dtxt.Substring(7, 2) + @"/" + dtxt.Substring(0, 4);
```

The text I'm trying to parse with it is `yyyyMMdd`. So from `20150309` I need `03/09/2015`. I don't use `dateTime` format as both the input and output are strings.

The issue is I get `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`. `string.Substring(X, Y)` should get the substring from the `X` index for `Y` length, shouldn't it?

Comment: Hint: indexes are 0-based. So a substring of "20150309" starting at index 7 will start with 9, and can only have a length of 1...

Comment: You are getting the error because the parameters should be (4,2), (6, 2) and (0, 4).  However, you should use the date functions as others have suggested.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use string operations in such a case.

Parse it to `DateTime` and format it with `.ToString()` method like;

```
string s = "20150309";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Dump(); //03/09/2015
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can convert this to `DateTime` and then back to any  string represantaion with the help of [`ToString(string format, IFormatProvider provider)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tfzyc64(v=vs.110).aspx) overload:

```
 var result = DateTime.ParseExact(dtxt, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None)
                      .ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

And don't forget to pass `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` as input while parsing. Not all cultures use the same format for dates and decimal currency values. ***Invariant culture*** is a special culture that you can always use in any .NET application.

By the way, the reason of exception in your code is you have not found the starting indices of month and day properly. You can change your code as:

```
string date = dtxt.Substring(4, 2) + @"/" + dtxt.Substring(6, 2) + @"/" + dtxt.Substring(0, 4);
```

But, of course it is not recommended to use operations on strings like this.